# Passing arguments to a Python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I want to pass arguments to a Python script in two ways,

```
python main.py --source=aws
```

and

```
python main.py source aws
```

This is my current code,

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--s", "--source", help='Flag to choose source')
```

This makes the first option possible. How do I make the second option possible?

Comment: What is the benefit of providing both ways? There's no clean, simple way to support both.

Comment: The current code also allows: `python main.py --source aws`.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a way to do that with Argparse. The only way to do that is by filtering stdin using sys.argv.

```
import argparse
import sys

mangle_my_args = ['s', 'source']
arguments=['--'+arg if arg in mangle_my_args else arg for arg in sys.argv[1:]]
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--s", "--source", help='Flag to choose source')
print(parser.parse_args(arguments))
```